# React unit test React saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, redux-saga

I'm having a bit of trouble with **testing sagas in React Native**.

I have read many examples, and I cannot seem to see what is a *proper way* to **unit test** a saga.

For example:

I have following saga:

```
function* getUsers(action) {
  try {
    const { id } = action.payload;
    const { data } = yield call(api.users.getUsers, { id });

    yield put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_USERS, payload: data });

  } catch (err) {
    yield call(errorHandler, err);
    yield put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_USERS_FAIL });
  }
}

function* getProfiles(action) {
  try {
    const { id } = action.payload;
    const { data } = yield call(api.users.getProfiles, { id });

    yield put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_PROFILES, payload: data });

  } catch (err) {
    yield call(errorHandler, err);
    yield put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_PROFILES_FAIL });
  }
}


export function* usersSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(userConstants.GET_USERS, getUsers);
  yield takeLatest(userConstants.GET_USER_PROFILES, getProfiles);
  
}
```

Test File:

```
import usersSaga from '../sagas/users/';

describe('Users Saga', () => {

it('should fetch users', () => {
   // what should I put in here
   // how should my test look like ?
});
})
```

How should my test look like, what should I test work, could someone provide me a basic example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Redux Saga Test Plan](http://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/unit-testing/) to test watcher and worker sagas.

> For unit testing, Redux Saga Test Plan exports a `testSaga` function that creates a mock saga for you to assert effects on.

E.g.

`saga.ts`:

```
import { call, put, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { api, errorHandler } from './api';
import { userConstants } from './actionTypes';

export function* getUsers(action) {
  try {
    const { id } = action.payload;
    const { data } = yield call(api.users.getUsers, { id });

    yield put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_USERS, payload: data });
  } catch (err) {
    yield call(errorHandler, err);
    yield put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_USERS_FAIL });
  }
}

export function* getProfiles(action) {
  try {
    const { id } = action.payload;
    const { data } = yield call(api.users.getProfiles, { id });

    yield put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_PROFILES, payload: data });
  } catch (err) {
    yield call(errorHandler, err);
    yield put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_PROFILES_FAIL });
  }
}

export function* usersSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(userConstants.GET_USERS, getUsers);
  yield takeLatest(userConstants.GET_USER_PROFILES, getProfiles);
}
```

`actionTypes.ts`:

```
export const userConstants = {
  LOAD_USERS: 'LOAD_USERS',
  LOAD_USERS_FAIL: 'LOAD_USERS_FAIL',
  LOAD_PROFILES: 'LOAD_PROFILES',
  LOAD_PROFILES_FAIL: 'LOAD_PROFILES_FAIL',
  GET_USERS: 'GET_USERS',
  GET_USER_PROFILES: 'GET_USER_PROFILES',
};
```

`api.ts`:

```
export const api = {
  users: {
    async getUsers(params) {},
    async getProfiles(params) {},
  },
};

export function errorHandler(err) {}
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { testSaga } from 'redux-saga-test-plan';
import { getProfiles, getUsers, usersSaga } from './saga';
import { userConstants } from './actionTypes';
import { api, errorHandler } from './api';

describe('68294010', () => {
  describe('usersSaga', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
      testSaga(usersSaga)
        .next()
        .takeLatest(userConstants.GET_USERS, getUsers)
        .next()
        .takeLatest(userConstants.GET_USER_PROFILES, getProfiles)
        .finish()
        .isDone();
    });
  });

  describe('getUsers', () => {
    it('should get data', () => {
      testSaga(getUsers, { payload: { id: 1 } })
        .next()
        .call(api.users.getUsers, { id: 1 })
        .next({ data: 'teresa teng' })
        .put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_USERS, payload: 'teresa teng' })
        .finish()
        .isDone();
    });
    it('should handle error', () => {
      const err = new Error('network');
      testSaga(getUsers, { payload: { id: 1 } })
        .next()
        .call(api.users.getUsers, { id: 1 })
        .throw(err)
        .call(errorHandler, err)
        .next()
        .put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_USERS_FAIL })
        .finish()
        .isDone();
    });
  });

  describe('getProfiles', () => {
    it('should get profile', () => {
      testSaga(getProfiles, { payload: { id: 1 } })
        .next()
        .call(api.users.getProfiles, { id: 1 })
        .next({ data: 'teresa teng' })
        .put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_PROFILES, payload: 'teresa teng' })
        .finish()
        .isDone();
    });
    it('should handle error', () => {
      const err = new Error('network');
      testSaga(getProfiles, { payload: { id: 1 } })
        .next()
        .call(api.users.getProfiles, { id: 1 })
        .throw(err)
        .call(errorHandler, err)
        .next()
        .put({ type: userConstants.LOAD_PROFILES_FAIL })
        .finish()
        .isDone();
    });
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/68294010/saga.test.ts
  68294010
    usersSaga
      ✓ should pass (3 ms)
    getUsers
      ✓ should get data (1 ms)
      ✓ should handle error (1 ms)
    getProfiles
      ✓ should get profile (1 ms)
      ✓ should handle error

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |     100 |      100 |      50 |     100 |                   
 actionTypes.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 api.ts         |     100 |      100 |       0 |     100 |                   
 saga.ts        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       5 passed, 5 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.04 s
```